# How to know if document has loaded

Tags: javascript, dom, load

I have a piece of JS code which needs to determine **if DOM has loaded**. I know there are several ways of executing JS code when DOM has loaded like:

```
$(document).ready(function() { ... }); // Jquery version

document.body.onload = function() { ... } // Vanila JS way
```

I am looking for some method which looks like

```
function isDOMLoaded() {
    // Do something to check if DOM is loaded or not
    // return true/false depending upon logic
}
```

**PS: Update (Post Answer Accept)**
I happen to see jquery also use the same approach to check if DOM has loaded. Take a look at the [Implementation of jquery.ready() here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/eee2eaf1d7a189d99106423a4206c224ebd5b848/speed/jquery-basis.js)

```
bindReady: function() {
    if ( readyBound ) {
        return;
    }

    readyBound = true;

    // Catch cases where $(document).ready() is called after the
    // browser event has already occurred.
    if ( document.readyState === "complete" ) {
        return jQuery.ready();
    }

    ...
```

Comment: probably you can set a flag on dom load and check that flag to see whether dom has loaded

Comment: Actually, my javascript code comes into page at runtime So I can't bind events on document.ready. I just needed to check some boolean variable kind of thing which Yeahman has answered.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
function isDOMLoaded(){
 return document.readyState == 'complete';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use something like this

```
function isLoaded() {
    return (document.readyState === 'ready' ||
            document.readyState === 'complete')
}
```

Check for `ready` and `complete` status.

`ready` is only there for a short moment but do reflect when the DOM is ready. When the page is completely loaded however the status is changed to 'complete'. If you happen to check only for ready the function will fail, so we also check for this status.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
var flgDOMLoaded=false; //Set a global variable
 $(document).ready(function() { 
   flgDOMLoaded= true;
  // Some code
 });

function isDOMLoaded() {
   return flgDOMLoaded; // return it. 
  //You don't need this function at all. You could just access window.flgDOMLoaded
}
```